# use mariadb-connector-cpp with cmake project

Tags: c++, database, mariadb, client, c++20

[github repo](https://mariadb-connector-cpp). i am using c++20 with cmake on visual studio to program on wsl and getting error loading shared library. can't find file libmariadb.so.3.

I used the build instructions to build it for Debian & Ubuntu on wls and it was installed in these paths.
[image: lib path] [image: include path]

so in my cmake I included

```
find_package(mariadbcpp)
include_directories("/usr/local/include/mariadb")
link_directories("/usr/local/lib/mariadb")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mariadbcpp)
```

when I run I get the following error

> error while loading shared libraries: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried running

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

and I also tried including this in my top level cmake

```
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE) 
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/usr/local/lib/mariadb")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get it working you just need to add this to your cmake

```
include_directories("/usr/include/mariadb") #path to include folder
add_library(mariadbcpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET mariadbcpp PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/libmariadbcpp.so") #path to libmariadbcpp.so
```

then just include

```
#include <conncpp.hpp>
```

in source

to install I followed [this](https://mariadb.com/docs/connect/programming-languages/cpp/install/) Debian/Ubuntu and in step 10 the command to install libmariadbcpp.so.3 and lib/mariadb... should have been lib64/mariadb...
like so

```
sudo install lib64/mariadb/libmariadbcpp.so /usr/lib
sudo install lib64/mariadb/libmariadbcpp.so.3 /usr/lib
sudo install lib64/mariadb/plugin/* /usr/lib/mariadb/plugin
```